# Map JSON to array of my model - ObjectMapper

Tags: json, swift, objectmapper

I am having the trouble in mapping json to my objects array with ObjectMapper. Here is my model object.

```
class Participant : Mappable {

var user_global_id: String!
var user_app_id: String!

init(){
}

required init?(_ map: Map) {
}

// Mappable
func mapping(map: Map) {
    user_global_id    <- map["user_global_id"]
    user_app_id    <- map["user_app_id"]
}
}
```

And my json looks: `"[{\"user_global_id\":5093363330056192,\"user_app_id\":11}]"`

I am calling ObjectMapper:

```
let participants = Mapper<[Participant]>().map(json["registeredParticipants"])
```

Above line gives error:  `Type '[Participant]' does not conform to protocol 'Mappable'`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The main mistake is in passing the array as generic attribute. Here is the solution

```
 Mapper<Participant>().mapArray(json["registeredParticipants"])
```